# Creating a Hollow Rectangle Using Asterisks in Java

Tags: java, draw, shapes

This is a homework assignment. However, I've completed almost all the code and am missing just one piece. The program is supposed to print out a rectangle according to user specified height and width values. The rectangle needs to be hollow, however it is not. I'm new to Java, so I'm not sure what to implement in my code to make the rectangle hollow. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
Example.

Height =4 Width =8

What I get

```
********
********
********
********
```

What I need

```
********
*      *
*      *
********
```

Below is my code. Thanks for the help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Rectangle 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int height;
int width;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Please enter the height of the rectangle.");
height = keyboard.nextInt();
if (height < 0)
{
    height = 1;
}
System.out.println("Please enter the width of the rectangle.");
width = keyboard.nextInt();
if(width < 0)
{
    width = 1;
}

for(int h = 0; h < height; h++) 
{ 
    for(int w = 0; w < width; w++) 
    { 
        System.out.print("*"); 
    } 
    System.out.println(" "); 
} 
}
}
```

Comment: Add an if condition while printing the *. The condition should check for h and w to be either 0 or max(height-1 or width-1). Giving out more hint than this will require me to put the modified code here. I am sure you will not want it.

Answer (score 1):

```
   /**
    * Created by stanfordude on 3/11/15.
    *  These methods should work... I tested them     
    */
  public class HelpNewb {
     public void drawLine(int length, String s) {
          for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
              System.out.print(s);
        }
 public void drawHollowLine(int length) {

    System.out.print("*");
    drawLine(length-2, " ");
    System.out.print("*");
}


public void drawRectangle(int height, int length) {
    drawLine(length, "*");
    System.out.println();
    for(int i=0; i<height-2; i++) {
        drawHollowLine(length);
        System.out.println();
    }
    drawLine(length, "*");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HelpNewb().drawRectangle(6, 10);
}

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to include an if-statement to control when the program should print an asterisk or an empty space.  In this case, we only want to print the asterisk at the first & last row, as well as first & last column.

```
if(h==0 || h==height-1 || w==0 || w==width-1) {
    System.out.print("*");
} else {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Hi I have a simple code that might help you

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Practice{
  static Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);

 public static void main(String [] args)        
{
  System.out.print("Enter the height of the rectangle: ");
  int h = sc.nextInt();

  System.out.print("Enter the width of the rectangle: ");
  int w = sc.nextInt();

  for(int j=1; j<=h; j++)
  {  
    for(int i=1; i<=w; i++)
    {
      if(j ==1 || j==h || i==1 || i==w)  
      {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      else
      {
           System.out.print(" ");
      }
    }
     System.out.println();
  } 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for the exercise from the book Java How to Program (10th edition) and you can only use `while` loops and `if..else` statements then you might do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sides;
    System.out.print("Enter the length of the side of the square: ");
    sides = input.nextInt();

    int count = 0;
    int counter = 1;

    // Prints out the first row 
    while (count < sides) {
        System.out.print("*");
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    count = 0;

    // Prints out the hollow part
    while (counter < sides-1) {
        System.out.print("*");  // Prints the '*' at the beginning of the row
        while (count < sides - 2) { 
            System.out.print(" "); // Prints the spaces
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("*"); // Prints the '*' at the end of the row
        count=0;
        counter++;
    }

    // Prints out the last row(same as the first one)
    while (count < sides) {
        System.out.print("*");
        count++;
    }
}
```